# How can I show a wait cursor during whole WPF render cycle?

Tags: wpf

I wrote a project that's creating a hierarchy diagram using nested controls.

When run on a complex data source, having WPF paint the diagram comprising approx. 2,000 nested controls takes quite a while.

A property change, like border stroke width, may trigger the whole render cycle, incl. Measure, Arrange etc.

I'd like to show a wait cursor for the whole render cycle, including Measure, Arrange and everything else happening before WPF presents the final result on screen. Is there a set of events I can register with to set the mouse cursor appropriately?

Comment: You may set the cursor in an action that you pass to the `Dispatcher` with a [DispatcherPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) of your choice.

Comment: There is no single entry point where I could call that action. Virtually any change to any of the visual properties of any of the controls will trigger Measure/Arrange/Render. I need to hook into this process, so every time Measure/Arrange/Render of the `ScrollViewer` content is triggered, regardless of the command, binding, source or target that triggered the Measure/Arrange/Render process, I need a way to have the mouse cursor switch to `Wait` application wide at the start and back again at the end of the Measure/Arrange/Render process.